# Plot 3d surface using matplotlib of user defined function with > 2 arguments

Tags: python, plot, 3d, surface

I have a function with 6 arguments, say fn. I also have two arrays, one 'x' array and one 'y' array, filled with values that I would like to evaluate fn on (with the other 4 arguments being held constant the entire time). I'd like to get a 3d plot of fn iterated over x,y. Is there anyway to do this without redefining the function to be a function of 2 arguments with the other 4 held constant?

I have seen matplotlib's meshgrid and it seems like a direction to head in, but i'm not sure that calling my function on a meshgrid will work because of the additional four (constant) parameters. Any ideas? Will post detailed code if requested.

Comment: The easiest solution is to just make another function that accepts only two arguments and calls your function with the appropriate fixed values of the other arguments.

Comment: You could always use a `lamda` function with `x, y` inputs and the other four fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something called currying (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

```
def wrapper_function_factory(fun, c, d, e f):
    return lambda a, b: fun(a, b, c, d, e, f)

fixed_fun = wrapper_function_factor(fun, C, D, E, F)

Z = fixed_fun(x, y)  # assuming your function can do broadcasting
```